# Name prefix in aws policy resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need an iam to allow some actions but only if the resource name contains the prefix 'my-prefix-'
I tried something like:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:::my-prefix-*"
```

But it didn't work.

My problem is basically this one, but not only for s3 resource, since I need for others resources too:
[Variable resource name in AWS IAM policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577331/variable-resource-name-in-aws-iam-policy)
I tried that solution and it didn't work

Comment: Any update on this?